# How to get Eclipse tools working nicely with JSP?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, ide, intellij-idea

How do you get Eclipse to work properly with JSP files as it does with Java files?

Specifically:

- Eclipse "Find references" (Right click on method, references, workspace) doesn't find references in JSP files.
- Eclipse refactoring (Right click on method, refactor, rename) doesn't rename references in JSP files.

We're using Eclipse 3.2.2.

Comment: This question was asked in 2009.  JSP support is much better in the latest version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we switched to IntelliJ which does this very nicely out of the box..

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse 3.2 (Callisto) has been [released in 2006](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases)... and it looks like refactoring in JSP file was [not supported at the time](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg09344.html).

An upgrade might be in order (if your environment/policy at work does support upgrading this software).

However, even with 3.4, that is not (well) supported, as illustrated by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538239/does-the-eclipse-web-tools-project-handle-refactoring-inside-jsps).